# How to find tree in a graph with maximal possible height?

Tags: tree, graph-traversal

You should assume that regular graph is given. Graph is not multigraph and has no self-edges. I am looking for algo with upper bound of O(n^2)

Comment: Show your attempts, and the problems they have. What did researching this problem give you?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tree with maximal height will include (from root to leaf) the *longest* possible path in G.

The problem of finding the longest path in an unweighted, undirected graph [is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem). By consequence there is no O(n²) algorithm to solve it.